# Gridview shows 4 items on line on emulator but 3 on the actual phone

Tags: android, gridview, layout, adapter

Why would my gridview adapter display 4 images on a line in my Lg g4 emulator(5,5 inch, 1440x2560) but on the actual device it shows 3 pictures on a line, with black spaces in between? Same resolution, both real and emulated devices have virtual buttons. Both running Android 6.

What could it be?

Comment: Can you show screenshots?

Comment: how about your xml code?

Comment: have you tried `android:numColumns="3"`?

Comment: I have numColumns = "3"

Answer (score 0):

go to the layout design of your grid view display and check android:numColumns property. If it is not available then assign property i.e

android:numColumns="3" ------ amount of column per view
android:numColumns="auto" ----------- automatically gives depending of screen size